# python matplotlib updating window after pressing Home

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib graph and a toolbar that has the standard buttons, Home, Left, Right, etc.

The graph plots the new data coming in perfectly fine if no buttons are pressed. If the user zooms in on an area however and returns "home", the graph window doesn't update with new data, it just shows the start of the plot.

I want to change the functionality of the home button in the toolbar so that when pressed, the plot automatically resumes updating from the latest data points. To that end, I've subclassed the navigation toolbar:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx, _load_bitmap
class MyToolbar(NavigationToolbar2Wx):
    ON_CUSTOM_HOME = wx.NewId()
    def __init__(self, plotCanvas):
        NavigationToolbar2Wx.__init__(self, plotCanvas)
        self.DeleteToolByPos(6) # 6 Is the subplot button
        self.DeleteToolByPos(1) # 1 is the Home button. 

        self.AddSimpleTool(self.ON_CUSTOM_HOME, _load_bitmap('stock_home.xpm'),
                       'Restore limits', 'Restores to default view')
        wx.EVT_TOOL(self, self.ON_CUSTOM_HOME, self.on_home)

   def on_home(self, evt):
      #code for the home button..?
```

I suppose I have to pass the matplot window/graph as a parameter to the toolbar, but I don't know what commands there are to enable automatic updating of the x-axis again after a button has been pressed. Please advise!

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to do this?